# IIS - Rewriting URL with %2520

Tags: iis-7, character-encoding, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a URL with `"%2520"` in the path, to another URL.

The URL looks like this:

```
"www.example.com/this%2520url/index.html"
```

I tried several different `RegEx` methods, but with no success yet.

I'm using `IIS 7` with the `URL` rewrite module.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I don't see any issue, can you be more precise?

Comment: I just wanna redirect the URL to another page. The important part is, i can't "catch" a URL with a double encoded space, like %2520, since no RegEx method seems to be able to read it.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?